# How to detect if document.getSelection().modify('extend', 'forward', 'word') got to the end of document?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

How can I detect if `document.getSelection().modify('extend', 'forward', 'word');` touches the end of the document? It does not work analyzing the text (length == 0) because for example an empty `<p>`-Tag is considered as an word. I already tried to check the client rect of the range objects (and compare to previous range). But on some documents the cursor "jumps" between two positions, after reaching the end of the document. So this is not reliable.

The `modify` function always returns `undefined`. So this does not help.

Used browser: Microsoft Edge (in my case it's enough, when running in this browser).

**Example (simplified code, not real word code):**

```js
let words = [];
let proceed = true;
let sel = document.getSelection();
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
let range = document.createRange();

range.setStart(p[0], 0);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);

for(let i = 0; i < 100 && proceed; i++) {
  sel.collapseToEnd();
  sel.modify('extend', 'forward', 'word');
  
  if(sel.rangeCount > 0)
    words.push(sel.getRangeAt(0).toString());
}

console.log('Words:', words);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD Html 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>
<body>
<p>One Two</p><p>Three Four</p><p>Six Seven</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example: How to set proceed to false, at the last word? How to get rid of the counter variable `i` without ending in an endless loop?

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems hard to detect the end of the document. I think we need some workarounds. What is your final goal? If you only want to get all the words in the page, you can filter the words array at the end of the code to remove the empty elements. Or can you move forward by `paragraph`? If you can, then you can end the for loop when `words[i]==""`.

Comment: I don't know the length of the document. There might be 100.000 words or just 1. So a loop with a special amount of iterations is no option. In real situation I want to select every word one by one and check the selected word (and replace it if needed). My current approach is to detect an empty string, but than calling the modify function 10 more times to see, if it was a false end. So there is really no way to detect this? I'm realy wondering, why the modify function has not simply a return value. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to achieve this using `modify()` so I make a workaround. You say you *want to select every word one by one and check the selected word (and replace it if needed)*. How about this: First get all the words in the page, then check them one by one in a loop and replace it when it meets some conditions.

The sample code is like below. Here I assume that we need to replace word "Three" with "Zero":

```js
function CheckAndReplace() {
  var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  if (!paragraphs) return;
  var j = 0;
  while (j < paragraphs.length) {
    // Parse the text into an array
    var arr = paragraphs[j].innerHTML.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      console.log(arr[i]);
      if (arr[i] == "Three") {
        var replaced = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[j].innerHTML.replace("Three", "Zero");
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[j].innerHTML = replaced;
      }
    }
    j++
  }
}
```

```html
<p>One Two</p>
<p>Three Four</p>
<p>Six Seven</p>
<input type="button" onclick="CheckAndReplace();" value="Check And Replace" />
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this idea. I think I'll need some time to tune this. The idea is, that the user can type the selection in a dialog. It would be nice to have the replaced word selected. Also multiple occurrences of the same word in the same paragraph should not be replaced, when the first occurrence is replaced. May be it's possible to tune this to have a selection for the appropriate word that should be replaced.

Comment: Then you'll need to adjust the code according to your demands. You can come back if you make any progress.